# Using RVsitebuilder

Tags: seo

Does anybody have knowledge of using Rvsitebuilder to build a site? Would love some advice!

Comment: What does this have to do with SEO? And why not try something not so ghetto (e.g. Drupal, Joomla, or FUEL CMS)?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that it's a piece of junk!